# Using ajax json response in an angular scope variable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, ajax, api

Okay so I'm connecting to a freshdesk API to get what tickets are open. Now I want to display this dynamically in my own web app using angular.js. At the moment I am receiving a json response from the freshdesk API but I cannot store it into a variable to then parse into my angular controller $scope.tickets variable.

How can I do this, is there a better way? I am quite new to angular and jQuery so open to any suggestions on how I can do this.

This is my code :

```
var jsonData;
function getData() {

$.support.cors = true;
var settings = {
"async" : true,
"crossDomain" : true,
"url" : "https://helpdesk.example.com/helpdesk/tickets.json",
"type" : "GET",
"headers" : { "authorization": basicAuth, "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    //alert(response);
    console.log(response);
    jsonData = response;
});
}
```

I have tried jsonData = JSON.parse(response);  But this doesn't work and it is a valid json response.

My angular controller:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.tickets = jsonData;
});
```

Comment: you don't need to parse the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to parse the json response. example, if your response look like this.

```
[
{"ticket_id":1,"desc":"some desc"},
{"ticket_id":2,"desc":"some issues"}
]
```

then you can directly use it as

```
var tickets= response.data;
console.log(tickets[0].desc);
```

you can than directly set the scope variable $scope.tickets. Also you should use http service of angular for making http calls rather than ajax.

Comment: Yes I used the angular http calls instead and is now working perfectly. Now my only problem is that some people who sign in on our ticketing system, sign in with google, how do I authorize them from the API side in my code. I usually just do a basic auth function but that doesn't work for anyone signing in with google.

Comment: store a token after logging as cookie or in localstorage, then send it on each api call, you can write interceptor for adding a authorization header

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning a lot, how do I that? How do I get the user to sign into google and received a token for using the freshdesk API and than storing it into a cookie to use later when calling other requests?

Comment: after redirecting from google, you have to create a auth token which can be used for making http calls to freshdesk api

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.tickets = [];
    var _data = angular.fromJson(response.data);
         $scope.tickets = _data;
});
```

Try this I think this may helps.